# Sorting and Re-formatting a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Need help with the following:

1. Reading from one string until another specified string.
2. Merging 2 strings on separate lines onto 1 line I tried strip() and this was not successful.
3. Create 2 separate arrays from the text provided.

Given:

```
Cat Chores
Get 
cat food.
Dog Chores
Get
dog food. Walk Dog.
```

Desired output:

```
Cat Chores
Get cat food.
```

These sentences are separated because they will be put in an array.

```
Dog Chores
Get dog food. Walk Dog.
```

Final output:

```
cat_chores = [Get cat food.]
dog_chores = [Get dog food. , Walk Dog]
```

Here is my code:

```py
# Remove whitespace and reformat the file
with open('chores.txt',"r") as f:
  text = input.read()
  text = [lines.strip() for lines in text] 

with open('chores.txt',"w") as f:
  f.writelines(text)
  f.close

# Re-open the file to create the arrays.
with open('chores.txt',"r") as f:
  text = input.read()

if "Cat Chores" in text:
  print (line,end='')
  print(next(input),end='')

if "Dog Chores" in text:
  print (line,end='')
  print(next(input),end='')
```

Comment: An altogether better approach is to use a well-defined machine-readable file format like JSON or YAML; then the code will be trivial. Your format does not seem to be well-defined at all; how would the reader know when something is a new group?

Comment: You need to loop through the `lines` in `text` variable after reading the file. It might even be better just to see if `Chores` exists in the line and if it does, then use the opening word in the like as a key to a `dict` which value would be the chores listed. As triple mentioned this might not be the best file format for your problem, you can try JSON to make it simpler.

Comment: Thanks! The data was provided via .txt format. So I will convert it to json in the future however the .txt file not formatted well. @tripleee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
chores = {}
action = ''
with open('chores.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.read().splitlines():
        line = line.strip()  # your original data had trailing spaces. this is to remove them
        if 'Chores' in line:  # check if line is a grouping
            current_chore = line
            chores[current_chore] = []
        elif len(line.split(' ')) == 1:  # check if line is an action
            action = line + ' '
            continue
        else:
            chores[current_chore].append(action + line)
            action = ''

with open('chores.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(chores))
    f.close
```

It will output:

```
{'Cat Chores': ['Get cat food.'], 'Dog Chores': ['Get dog food. Walk Dog.']}
```

This assumes that a grouping always contains 'Chores', action is always 1 word, and outputs a string of a dictionary. My version doesn't separate 'Get dog food.' and 'Walk Dog.' but if you want that you can add a split() on '. ' and handle it. The formatting of your input data is horrible and really shouldn't be used as is.